# Rule-based restructuring of nodes

Tags: xslt

Supposed I have the following XML file with nodes I would like to rearrange based on rules:

```
<root>   
  <subsection key="KeyR">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyE">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyG">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyH">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyI">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyF">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyJ">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyL">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyA"/>
  <subsection key="KeyM">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyN">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyO">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyS">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyP">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyQ">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyD">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyB"/>
  <subsection key="KeyT">Some text</subsection>
  <subsection key="KeyK">Some text</subsection> 
  <subsection key="KeyZ">Some text</subsection>  
</root>
```

and rules for the rearrangement like the following ones:

```
section01
  KeyA
  KeyM
  KeyZ
section02
  KeyL
  KeyN
  KeyP
section03
  ..
  ..
section04
 ..
```

These rules assign the key of a subsection to a new parend section. So that the following XML file would result:

```
<root>
  <section1>
    <subsection key="KeyA"/>
    <subsection key="KeyM">Some text</subsection>
    <subsection key="KeyZ">Some text</subsection>
  </section1>
  <section2>
    <subsection key="KeyL">Some text</subsection>
    <subsection key="KeyN">Some text</subsection>
    <subsection key="KeyP">Some text</subsection>
  </section2>
  <section3>
    ...
  </section3>
  ...
</root>
```

Would be an XSL transformation the appropriate means? How would such a transformation look? What would be an appropriate manifestation for the rules so that the rules can be maintained easily?

Comment: I don't think I understand the rules. Why are `KeyA`, `KeyM` and `KeyZ` grouped together? Besides, it is generally a bad idea to introduce numbering in element names (`section1`).

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 ?    Also, is the textual outline you provide going to be an input file literally or is it merely intended to sketch the look of the XSLT rules?

Comment: "*What would be an appropriate manifestation for the rules so that the rules can be maintained easily?*" That's exactly what I was going to ask you. We know nothing about what these codes represent in real life, and even less about how/when/where/by whom these rules need to "maintained". In terms of the transformation, I suppose it would be convenient to have them hard-coded in the XSLT stylesheet itself. Alternatively, an external XML document (with a known name and path) would also be quite easy to work with.

Comment: KeyA, KeyM and KeyZ are grouped together because of the first four lines of the sketched rules. The first four lines stand for the mapping between the section and its subsections. The node section01 has to be created and the following three subsections have to be grouped under this node. At the moment the rules are in included in different php files and now the objective is to have some kind of text file or database table where the mapping between sections and subsections is defined. Based on this, the respective nodes of the input XML files shall be rearranged.

Comment: Will your database be able to export the rules on demand (or on every change) as an XML file with known name to a known location (where it will be accessible to the XSLT file by means of a hard-coded path to the file)?

Answer (score 1):

If you could have a rules.xml file living (for example) in the same directory as the XSLT stylesheet file, in (for example) the following format:

**rules.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <section id="01">
        <key>KeyA</key>
        <key>KeyM</key>
        <key>KeyZ</key>
    </section>
    <section id="02">
        <key>KeyL</key>
        <key>KeyN</key>
        <key>KeyP</key>
    </section>
</rules>
```

you could then apply the following stylesheet to your input:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sub" match="subsection" use="@key" />
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('rules.xml')/rules/section">
    <xsl:variable name="keys" select="key" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$root">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('sub', $keys)"/>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <section id="01">
      <subsection key="KeyA"/>
      <subsection key="KeyM">Some text</subsection>
      <subsection key="KeyZ">Some text</subsection>
   </section>
   <section id="02">
      <subsection key="KeyL">Some text</subsection>
      <subsection key="KeyN">Some text</subsection>
      <subsection key="KeyP">Some text</subsection>
   </section>
</root>
```

---

### Edit:

To suppress section rules that do not have matching subsections in the input document, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sub" match="subsection" use="@key" />
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('file2.xml')/rules/section">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name="keys" select="key" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$root">
            <xsl:if test="key('sub', $keys)">
                <section id="{$id}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('sub', $keys)"/>
                </section>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How would I modify the stylesheet to ensure, that sections from the rules.xml without matching key in the input xml file would not appear in the resulting xml file? For example if none of "KeyL", "KeyN" and "KeyP" would be contained in input, section with id 2 should not be in output