# Filtering XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Supposed I have the following XML input file file:

```
<root> 
  <NodeX> 
      ... 
  </NodeX>  
  <NodeY> 
      ... 
  </NodeY>  
  <Description>
      <section01>
         <subsection key="KeyA">Some text</subsection>
         <subsection key="KeyB">Some text</subsection>
      </section1>

      <section02>
         <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
      </section2>

      <section03>
         <subsection key="KeyD">Some Text</subsection>
      </section3>

   </Description>  
   ...
</root>
```

And another XML file with "rules" where the keys of the subsections are listed together with an audience attribute.

Example excerpt:

```
<rules>
    <subsection id="01">
        <key audience="internalOnly">KeyA</key>
        <key audience="internalOnly">KeyB</key>
    </subsection>

    <subsection id="02">
        <key>KeyC</key>
    </subsection>
<rules>
```

I try to write an XSL transformation that removes subsections from the input XML file based on the value of the audience attribute in the rules XML fille. If the value is "internalOnly" the subsection has to be removed.

In the example the following output XML should result:

```
<root> 
  <NodeX> 
      ... 
  </NodeX>  
  <NodeY> 
      ... 
  </NodeY>  
  <Description>
      <section02>
         <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
      </section2>

      <section03>
         <subsection key="KeyD">Some Text</subsection>
      </section3>

   </Description>  
   ...
</root>
```

(The whole section01 is removed because both subsections are "internalOnly").

The problems are 1) the "lookup" in the rules XML file and 2) the removal of section elements if all the corresponding subsections are removed:

If the audience attribute would be included in the input XML file I would create the following XSLT for the requirement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subsection[@audience='internalOnly']"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your current XSL... and exact details of problem you have with it.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/22663044/rule-based-restructuring-of-nodes/

Comment: The rearrangement of nodes from my previous question is some kind of prerequirement for the removal process here. I would like to separate the removal step from the rearrangement step. I tried to write the XSL transformation on the basis of your previous answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/22663044/rule-based-restructuring-of-nodes/ but had problems to understand the usage of the XSLT key function. Is the usage of the XSLT key function appropriate for the lookup I need for here for removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the big difference between this and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663044/rule-based-restructuring-of-nodes/). If you want to exclude certain keys from the rules.xml document, then change the definition of the `keys` variable from:

```
<xsl:variable name="keys" select="key" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="keys" select="key[not(@audience='internalOnly')]" />
```

Everything else can remain as it was.

---

> had problems to understand the usage of the XSLT key function

That's something well-worth working on.