# Remove XML elements based on set of rules with logical conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove particular XML elements from the following XML input file based on a set of rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <NodeX>
        <Value key="A">0815</Value>
        <Value key="B">XYZ</Value>
        <Value key="C">12345</Value>
        <Value key="D">ABC</Value>
    </NodeX>
    <Description>
        <section01>
            <subsection key="KeyA">Some text</subsection>
            <subsection key="KeyB">Some text</subsection>
        </section01>

        <section02>
            <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
        </section02>

        <section03>
            <subsection key="KeyD">Some Text</subsection>
        </section03>
    </Description>  
</root>
```

The problem is that there are exceptions to these rules.

Example: In an XML input file of the form seen above the following 2 elements with key="KeyA" and key="KeyB" have to be removed if element Value with attribute key="A" contains "0815":

```
<subsection key="KeyA">Some text</subsection>
<subsection key="KeyB">Some text</subsection>
```

UNLESS: Value element with attribute key="B" contains "XYZ" AND Value element with attribute key="C" contains "12345" AND Value element with attribute key="D" contains "ABC"

So that in the case above no XML element would be removed, but the following input file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <NodeX>
        <Value key="A">0815</Value>
        <Value key="B">XYZ</Value>
        <Value key="C">23456</Value>
        <Value key="D">DEF</Value>
    </NodeX>
    <Description>
        <section01>
            <subsection key="KeyA">Some text</subsection>
            <subsection key="KeyB">Some text</subsection>
        </section01>

        <section02>
            <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
        </section02>

        <section03>
            <subsection key="KeyD">Some Text</subsection>
        </section03>
    </Description>  
</root>
```

would be transformed to the following output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <NodeX>
        <Value key="A">0815</Value>
        <Value key="B">XYZ</Value>
        <Value key="C">23456</Value>
        <Value key="D">DEF</Value>
    </NodeX>
    <Description>
        <section02>
            <subsection key="KeyC">Some text</subsection>
        </section02>

        <section03>
            <subsection key="KeyD">Some Text</subsection>
        </section03>
    </Description>  
</root>
```

The two subsection elements with the parent section01 element would be removed because of content of Value elements with attributes key="C" and key="D".

Is an XML manifestation like the following an suitable representation for the rules to be processed by XSL as suggested in one of my previous questions: ([Rule-based restructuring of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663044/rule-based-restructuring-of-nodes))?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <prod code="0815">
        <keys>
            <key>keyA</key>
            <key>keyB</key>
        </keys>
        <exceptions>
            <Value key="B">XYZ</Value>
            <Value key="C">12345</Value>
            <Value key="D">ABC</Value>
        </exceptions>
    </prod>

    <prod code="0815">
        <keys>
            <key>keyD</key>
        </keys>
        <exceptions>
            <Value key="E">ZZZ</Value>
        </exceptions>
    </prod>
</rules>
```

How to automatically create conditional tests from this "rules" in the XML file?

Exceptions can consist of any number of Value element entries.

Is generating an XSLT from the XML rules an appropriate approach?

Comment: I do not understand why the provided XML and the provided rules would turn into the provided result? Your "UNLESS" totally matches the provided XML. So to my opinion it should not remove anything...

Comment: My UNLESS totally matches the first input XML, where nothing is removed. But the second input file contains different content for Value elements with key = C (23456 insted of 12345) and key = D (DEF instead of ABC).

Answer (score 0):

To "remove" elements using XSLT, start with the Identity Transform (which copies everything)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then add one or more templates which match the things you want to remove. If you want to remove the entire subtree those templates should output nothing; if you want to discard the node but keep all its children, those templates should execute `<xsl:apply-templates select='node()'/>`

Comment: Yes, but the problematic part is the removal which has to be executed based on the XML structure sketched above. Especially the realization of the exceptions.

Comment: OK, so your question is really how to write match expressions to test for those conditions. Right?

Comment: Exactly. My problem is the connection between the transformation file and the file containing the rule set. The goal is that only the rule file has to be edited if there is a new condition. E.g. based on the entries in exception element the transformation has to exclude elements from removal without hardcoding it in the transformation file.